# Check logged in status javascript

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, long-polling

I am trying to check the current user logged in or not using long polling.

What is the best way to achieve this in terms of performance and bandwidth ?

I am not asking about long polling, but the best way to check user logged in or not.

I tried to use `GET` request to check the login status.

```
var logged = $.ajax( {url:url,'type':'get'} );

logged.done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){  // success  });

logged.fail(function((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){  // sometimes it failed });
```

and in PHP

```
if( is_logged() ){ echo 1; }else{ echo 0; }
```

So depending up on the response i can detect the status. This works well. However i am concerning about the bandwidth usage and ended up with type `HEAD`, so that it will only fetch header contents.

so i modified the php part to ..

```
if( !is_logged() ){
 header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized'); 
}
```

in a quick view i feel that there are no problem with approach. But comparatively i am new to PHP and feels that there may be some problems with this approach.

So is this the best approach to check login status ? or what is the best way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GET request is fine and I don't see anything wrong with your approach. Not sold on the idea of returning 1/0 saving you anything tangible or returning headers/status instead of a proper response.

Instead, echo a JSON response. `{ success: true, response: {logged_in: true}}`

I would also change your php script from displaying a 401 header and instead returning `{success: true, response: {logged_in: false}}`

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your response.  The above codes are examples only. And in second iteration i am using `head` instead of `get`, So i feel that there is no use by returning as JSON, Secondly i feel that echoing 1 is more efficient than returning json content which needs more resource, comparatively.

Comment: Is that difference in bytes between a 1 and a 20 character string going to be critical to the operation of your application? Down that road lies madness...

Comment: You're not going to like it but based on your question it sounds like you're optimizing prematurely. There is something to be said for optimization but I would highly recommend you not worry about what you're worrying about until you can define a problem area and justify the need for further optimization. We will all need more information to recommend something if you are truly worried about a few extra bytes in your ajax requests.

Comment: Pardon me Chris, If i am wrong. The fact is client is very picky and have very strict guidelines to implement all these things. I know that json is efficient in many ways. Anyway our discussion is going out of Question :D

Comment: Additionally please note that its not `get` its `head`.

Comment: Then we're done. You're using head. You're not going to save any overhead short of using websockets.